# Undefined reference to object. Possible wrong implementation

Tags: c++, object, header

I'm writing a program for a class in which I must make a card game where you must match a pair of cards. It uses a GUI written in Qt provided by the professor. I have a header file containing a class called CardDeck, which simulates a deck of cards. I have included this header file in the main .cpp file, yet whenever I try to call any member functions of this class, the compiler prints "undefined reference to `CardDeck::(member function)'". I have a .cpp file called CardDeck.cpp that defines the member functions that is in the project folder, but it may not compile right or something. I am fairly inexperienced, so I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated. I am using MinGW compiler with NetBeans IDE.

main.cpp:

```
#include "CardDeck.h"

using namespace std;

// Declare any global variables (your deck object) here:

CardDeck gdeck(9, 14, 2);

void shuffleCards(){
    gdeck.ShuffleDeck();
}
```

CardDeck.h:

```
#ifndef CARDDECK_H
#define CARDDECK_H

#include "PlayingCard.h"
#include <vector>

class CardDeck {

public:    
    CardDeck();
    CardDeck(int, int, int);
    void ShuffleDeck();

    void DisplayXCards(int);
    void DisplayContents() const;

private:
    std::vector<PlayingCard> deck;
    int begin;
    int end;
    int number_each;

};

#endif  /* CARDDECK_H */
```

CardDeck.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include "PlayingCard.h"
#include "CardDeck.h"


using namespace std;

CardDeck::CardDeck(){
    begin = 2;
    end = 14;    
}

CardDeck::CardDeck(int b, int e, int num_each){
    begin = b;
    end = e;
    number_each = num_each;
    char shapes[4] = {'H', 'S', 'C', 'D'};
    for(int k=0; k<number_each; k++){
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            for(int i = begin; i<= end; i++){
                PlayingCard pc(i, shapes[j]);
                deck.push_back(pc);
            }       
        }
    }            
}

void CardDeck::DisplayContents() const{
    for(int k=0; k<deck.size(); k++){
        cout << deck[k].DisplayName() << endl;
    }
}

void CardDeck::ShuffleDeck(){
    random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());
}

void CardDeck::DisplayXCards(int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout << deck[i].DisplayName() << endl;
    }
}
```

Makefile:

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: cs215pgm3
# Generated by qmake (2.01a) (Qt 4.8.0) on: Thu Mar 1 15:03:59 2012
# Project:  cs215pgm3.pro
# Template: app
# Command: c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/qmake.exe QMAKE_CC=C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/gcc.exe QMAKE_CXX=C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/g++.exe "QMAKE_CFLAGS=-g3 -gdwarf-2" "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS=-g3 -gdwarf-2" -o Makefile cs215pgm3.pro
#############################################################################

first: debug
install: debug-install
uninstall: debug-uninstall
MAKEFILE      = Makefile
QMAKE         = c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/qmake.exe
DEL_FILE      = rm
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
COPY          = cp
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = cp -r
INSTALL_FILE  = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
DEL_FILE      = rm
SYMLINK       = 
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
SUBTARGETS    =  \
        debug \
        release

debug: $(MAKEFILE).Debug FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug
debug-make_default: $(MAKEFILE).Debug FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug 
debug-make_first: $(MAKEFILE).Debug FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug first
debug-all: $(MAKEFILE).Debug FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug all
debug-clean: $(MAKEFILE).Debug FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug clean
debug-distclean: $(MAKEFILE).Debug FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug distclean
debug-install: $(MAKEFILE).Debug FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug install
debug-uninstall: $(MAKEFILE).Debug FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug uninstall
release: $(MAKEFILE).Release FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release
release-make_default: $(MAKEFILE).Release FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release 
release-make_first: $(MAKEFILE).Release FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release first
release-all: $(MAKEFILE).Release FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release all
release-clean: $(MAKEFILE).Release FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release clean
release-distclean: $(MAKEFILE).Release FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release distclean
release-install: $(MAKEFILE).Release FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release install
release-uninstall: $(MAKEFILE).Release FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release uninstall

Makefile: cs215pgm3.pro  c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/default/qmake.conf c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/modules/qt_webkit_version.pri \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/default_pre.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/debug.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/debug_and_release.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/default_post.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/rtti.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/exceptions.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/stl.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/shared.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/qt.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/thread.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/moc.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/windows.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/uic.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/include_source_dir.prf \
        c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/lib/qtmaind.prl
    $(QMAKE) QMAKE_CC=C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/gcc.exe QMAKE_CXX=C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/g++.exe "QMAKE_CFLAGS=-g3 -gdwarf-2" "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS=-g3 -gdwarf-2" -o Makefile cs215pgm3.pro
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/qconfig.pri:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/modules/qt_webkit_version.pri:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/default_pre.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/debug.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/debug_and_release.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/default_post.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/rtti.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/exceptions.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/stl.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/shared.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/qt.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/thread.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/moc.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/win32/windows.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/resources.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/uic.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/lex.prf:
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/features/include_source_dir.prf:
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\lib\qtmaind.prl:
qmake: qmake_all FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) QMAKE_CC=C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/gcc.exe QMAKE_CXX=C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/g++.exe "QMAKE_CFLAGS=-g3 -gdwarf-2" "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS=-g3 -gdwarf-2" -o Makefile cs215pgm3.pro

qmake_all: FORCE

make_default: debug-make_default release-make_default FORCE
make_first: debug-make_first release-make_first FORCE
all: debug-all release-all FORCE
clean: debug-clean release-clean FORCE
distclean: debug-distclean release-distclean FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile

check: first

debug-mocclean: $(MAKEFILE).Debug
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug mocclean
release-mocclean: $(MAKEFILE).Release
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release mocclean
mocclean: debug-mocclean release-mocclean

debug-mocables: $(MAKEFILE).Debug
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug mocables
release-mocables: $(MAKEFILE).Release
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release mocables
mocables: debug-mocables release-mocables
FORCE:

$(MAKEFILE).Debug: Makefile
$(MAKEFILE).Release: Makefile
```

Compiling/Error Message:

```
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.Debug
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Ben/Documents/CS 215/Programs/cs215Pgm3'
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/g++.exe -c -g3 -gdwarf-2 -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'debug' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/default' -o debug/cardwidget.o cardwidget.cpp
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/g++.exe -c -g3 -gdwarf-2 -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'debug' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/default' -o debug/cardwindow.o cardwindow.cpp
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/g++.exe -c -g3 -gdwarf-2 -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'debug' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/default' -o debug/main.o main.cpp
C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'debug' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/default' -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 cardwindow.h -o debug/moc_cardwindow.cpp
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/g++.exe -c -g3 -gdwarf-2 -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'debug' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/default' -o debug/moc_cardwindow.o debug/moc_cardwindow.cpp
C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'debug' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/default' -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 cardwidget.h -o debug/moc_cardwidget.cpp
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/g++.exe -c -g3 -gdwarf-2 -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'debug' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/default' -o debug/moc_cardwidget.o debug/moc_cardwidget.cpp
g++ -mthreads -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o debug/cs215pgm3.exe debug/cardwidget.o debug/cardwindow.o debug/cs215pgm3.o debug/main.o debug/moc_cardwindow.o debug/moc_cardwidget.o debug/qrc_cards.o  -L'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/lib' -lmingw32 -lqtmaind -lQtGuid4 -lQtCored4 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Ben/Documents/CS 215/Programs/cs215Pgm3'
debug/cs215pgm3.o: In function `Z12shuffleCardsv':
C:\Users\Ben\Documents\CS 215\Programs\cs215Pgm3/cs215pgm3.cpp:107: undefined reference to `CardDeck::ShuffleDeck()'
debug/cs215pgm3.o: In function `_static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
C:\Users\Ben\Documents\CS 215\Programs\cs215Pgm3/cs215pgm3.cpp:99: undefined reference to `CardDeck::CardDeck(int, int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [debug/cs215pgm3.exe] Error 1
make: *** [debug] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 9s)
```

Comment: How are you building, make file, managed build, or some other method? It sounds like the linker isn't including your CardDeck.obj file into the build. If you read the compiler output carefully can you tell if it is a compiler error or a linker error? In other words can you see output that CardDeck compiled cleanly?

Comment: It should be building using makefile. The main error message the compiler outputs is "Build Failed:, so I'm assuming it compiled incorrectly.

Comment: Can you show us the makefile?

Comment: Probably not, "Build" usually refers to the entire compile/link process. A .h file is just a _promise_ to the compiler that the items defined in that header will be available at link time. The linker will hold you to your promise. If your make file doesn't include the .obj file for CardDeck then the link will fail. I don't know your level of experience, have you built a simple C program with say a foo() method in a file separate from the main() method? Also see if you have an output panel that has more info than the error/warning panel.

Comment: To be even more explicit, it's possible your make file is **only** compiling main. It's not even compiling CardDeck. The fact that you said **"it should"** makes me think you haven't edited it to include CardDeck. Some IDEs will do this automatically for you. Typically they have the concept of a _project_ and when you add a new C++ unit to a project it updates the make file. **HOWEVER** not all IDES do this and if you're not using and IDE at all then you definitely have to do it yourself. It might also help us if you tell us what tool chain you are using.

Comment: Ok, I added the makefile and what the ide displays when the program fails. I have very little experience, so I don't really know what a foo() method is.

Comment: Also, I'm using NetBeans 7.1 IDE with the MinGW compiler. I believe that it automatically updates the makefile, as I have created programs before that have had multiple .cpp files and they worked fine without any manual editing of the makefile

Answer (score 0):

Look at your compiler output the first few lines show you are compiling cardwidget.cpp, cardwindow.cpp and main.cpp. There is no corresponding line for CardDeck.cpp. *(As well as what I assume are some mocked versions for unit testing)*.  The make file you posted showed no references to these files. I am no make expert but I suspect the makefile you posted is including another file *(possibly the MAKEFILE=Makefile)* that you did not include. Look into your project files and see if you can find the file that is specifying the above files, typically as I remember Makefiles there should be something like

```
SOURCES =
or
SOURCES +=
and 
HEADERS=
or
HEADERS +=
```

At any rate there *HAS* to be a reference to the source and header files by name so if you can search inside the content of files, find the one that has cardwidget.cpp and possibly cardwidget.h. Then see if you can modify that file to include CardDeck.cpp and CardDeck.h.

What you posted is so complex I suspect some file automated build tool is creating this for you and your development environment may have some other way for you to specify your new source and header files and then it updates the make files automatically. You need to read whatever documentation came with your compiler/build system. Failing that specify **Exactly** what build tools you are using and maybe someone experienced with those tools can help.